# Stop adding text in <textarea> after condition fulfill

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a textarea

```
<textarea rows="3" [(ngModel)]="formatObj.textAreaBox" (keyup)="onExtendexDelimeterKeyUp($event)"  #extendDelimiters></textarea>
```

I Want to stop adding text in the textarea after condition fulfills. I do not want to disable the textarea as a user can delete text inside textarea. I want want to stop keyup to execute using Angular 7

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `ng-maxlength`?

Comment: use the max length attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp - add it and set to current length, then remove when your condition is relaxed

Comment: max length value will not work as the condition is calculated dynamically and will not fit with max length

Comment: @VivekKumarShukla remove when your condition is relaxed - it's the only way i know that you can prevent more text, but still allow deletion.  Other than capturing keypresses, and managing contents

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
export class AppComponent  {
      maxLength = 10
      content = '';
}
<textarea 
    [(ngModel)]="content"
    [maxlength]="maxLength"
>
</textarea>
```